# How do I 'freeze' a block level element?

Tags: html, css

I have a text field and a button. When I increase the width of the button, it shifts the text field over. I want the text field to be in the center of the screen and the button to be to it's right. Why is this occurring and How can I 'freeze' the text field and let the button be on the right?

**HTML**

```
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
          <h1>content</h1>
          <p>More content</p>
      </header>
      <main>
          <h2>Add a ToDo!</h2>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your ToDo item!"></input>
          <button type="button">Submit</button>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

#container {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is will work for you.
Put **position:absolute** to button's css.

```
button {
   position:absolute;  
   margin-left:5px;  //added just for better appearance
   width: 100px;
   height: 25px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtLqa303/1/).